# How to map through the results of a MongoDB aggregate query in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I have a MongoDB aggregate query which uses two lookups. The data is being retrieved correctly and output as I would expect when I console log it. However, I've spent bloody hours trying to access the nested arrays and objects, with no luck so far and I need some help, please.

This is my query:

```
const pipeline = [
    {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'posts',
            'localField': 'likedThing',
            'foreignField': 'id',
            'as': 'likedPost'
        }
    }, {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'users',
            'localField': 'userId',
            'foreignField': 'id',
            'as': 'userData'
        }
    }, {
        '$match': {
            'userId': userId
        }
    }
  ]

const postdata = await db.collection('likes').aggregate(pipeline).toArray();
```

If we console.log(postdata):

```
[
    {
    _id: '0_m5wSs6WGuAtrfmQuHJI',
    likedThing: '617ba5d6df45df5616becb21',
    userId: 'GYmLSp0fL9dTuJvEuJVL0vsBYnX2',
    likedPost: [ [Object] ],
    userData: [ [Object] ]
},
{
    _id: 'Xs6GakQ_FVIbYUhtN_-e8',
    likedThing: '617ba277df45df5616becb20',
    userId: 'GYmLSp0fL9dTuJvEuJVL0vsBYnX2',
    likedPost: [ [Object] ],
    userData: [ [Object] ]
 }]
```

I then log the likedPost array/object  =>  console.log('likedPost: ',postdata[0].likedPost) which gives me:

```
likedPost:  [
    {
    _id: new ObjectId("617ba5d6df45df5616becb21"),
    userId: 'i3PYKSLvAcfEd1JdNSEh7qk8NJx1',
    post: 'some post.',
    }
 ]
```

I pass 'postdata' to a component to map through it:

```
<Feed postdata={postdata}/>
```

And in the Feed component I try to access 'post' value in the nested 'likedPost' array/object and I can't. Given the output of the console logs it seems to me to access to post value I should do the following:

```
{postdata.map((postdata, i) => (
    <Card
        key={i}
        post={postdata.likedPost[0].post}
        ...
    />
))}
```

But I get 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'post')' even though this console log outputs the post:

```
console.log('likedPost.post: ',postdata[0].likedPost[0].post)
```

I think it's something to do with likedPost being an array, hence the [0] above, containing an object. How do I access the 'post' key value within the likedPost array/object in my Feed component, please?

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for your reply. This gives me a "Cannot read property 'post' of undefined" so I removed the [0] which then doesn't give me any errors at all but the post value in the Card is empty.

Comment: [mapping over the data does work](https://jsfiddle.net/4xezowf7/). I did have to remove that weird `new ObjectId` from the data though. I'm not familiar enough with MDB to understand why it's delivering that structure back in your JSON.

Comment: Ah yes, the ObjectID is a MongoDB unique key thing which is actually an object I believe, which was probably messing up the mapping. I removed the field from the query. You JSFiddle works, but for whatever reason, I'm still getting the same error. I even did my own JS fiddle using the exact output from the logs, which works likes yours, but using the same format in my code still produces and error. https://jsfiddle.net/143jkso8/ Anyway, you've proved it works so if you put it in an answer I will mark it correct for you. There must be something weird with my code which I shall investigate more

Comment: I've not really solved anything so I won't add an answer. But good luck getting to the core of the problem!